# UiApp - Charts Vs. Visualization API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

This may seem like a lazy question but if i were to link all of the documentation I have read and the old SO posts I have trawled through this would rapidly turn into a very, very long post.

The simple question I have is '*how do I customise series colors/tooltips in a chart created using Charts Service displayed via UiApp embedded in a Google Site?*'

I know that this is [easily achievable using the Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), but unless I've missed a key point it is not possible to use the Visualization API library with UiApp? Charts Service appears to have extremely limited functionality in comparison.

I have included an example of my chart creation code below:

```js
...

var sampleData = Charts.newDataTable()
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Subject")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Target")
   //.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, {role: 'tooltip'})
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Level")
   .addRow([subjectArray[0], 10, /*'custom tooltip',*/ 9])
   .addRow([subjectArray[1], 11, 9]) 
   .build();

var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
   .setTitle('KS3 target vs. level')
   .setXAxisTitle('Subject')
   .setYAxisTitle('Grade')
   .setDimensions(1200, 500)
   .setDataTable(sampleData)
   .build();  

return UiApp.createApplication().add(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the Charts Service is a very limited subset of the Visualization API. If I understand your question correctly though, add `.setColors(array_of_colors)` before `.build()` on the chart.

`array_of_colors` should be an array of hexadecimal colors.

As an aside, `.setOption` allows you to set a lot of the properties available through the Visualization API (legend, title, axes, hAxis, vAxis, focusTarget, etc). I wish you could assign roles to DataTable columns, though.

Comment: Thanks Fred! that color advice was what I was looking for. 

I've used .setOption (not shown in this stripped down code) to set vAxis.tick and as a workaround (because I can't customise them) disabled tooltips.

Comment: Let's say I want to set the width and height for a chart. What is the syntax for setting options? I can't find any documentation and it seems to be different from the Visualization API method. Please help!

Comment: All the chart builders have a method called `setDimensions`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/column-chart-builder#setDimensions%28Integer,Integer%29